# Npm run dev on nuxt.js project isn't working on Mac M1

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I don't know if it has something to do with the mac but on my other windows computer everything is fine the display is good but when I switch to my mac and run an npm run dev there are a few pages that don't work not display.

I show you with the screenshots:

Here is on Mac M1 :

[image]
Nothing works on the navigation bar, even when I type in the url to access a page it doesn't work

Here is on Windows pc :

[image]

I wanted to know if this has ever happened to anyone because I don't understand the problem. The version of node.js on the mac is 16.13.0 and on my windows computer it's a version 15 but I think below 16 it's not compatible on mac M1. Thanks

Comment: Which browsers did you test it on?

Comment: Do you have a github repo, some errors?

Comment: Is it possible to move your project into docker (with your preferred node version) and run it from there? I just got a shipment notification on my M1 Pro Max today (finally 2 months later) so it looks like I will have to take this approach.

Comment: @ManiMirjavadi i test it on Safari and Google chrome on the mac and its the same for both

Comment: @kissu yes I have a Gitlab repo and I don't have any errors

Comment: @SimonK Oh yes I'll try but otherwise the thing I don't understand is that I can access the site, for example choose a category but as soon as I arrive on a specific page I can't do anything... I can't don't know where it comes from

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? If so, what?

Comment: @SimonK Thank's !!! Thanks to you I solved the problem with the console, it was just import problems in my code so why on windows it worked well like that I don't know but now it also works on the Mac. Thank you very much, so it was not a problem regarding the chip Apple Silicon have no fear for your MacBook Pro

Comment: Oh what a relief - you scared me!

Comment: @SimonK Haha sorry I also recently bought an M1 pro and it's amazing don't worry !

Comment: Feel free to post an answer for it to be accepted @SimonK

Answer (score 1):

remove the `.nuxt`, `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` directory then run

`npm install`